# grain in my render scene

Tags: rendering

[image: render image]

hi,I am pretty new to the blender and trying to render a scene by using a free vehicle model that I have downloaded,the model seems very detailed and texture ready,however I have noticed lot of grain around edge of the celling window.I have switched between eevee and cycles and crancked sample number to 1000 but unfortunately the grain still remain,does anybody has had similar problems?I'm here for a help,thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello :). That doesn't look like 'grain'. It looks more like overlapping geometry or problems with camera clipping distance (z-fighting).

Comment: yes,it was a z-fighting issue,thank you,Jachym!